# How to choose date range in angular

Tags: angularjs, date, date-range, sessionstorage

I'm going to try and explain this as good as I can because I am kind of a rookie with angular

I have my controller set up to store the date in session storage

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

In the html I have someone choose a date

```
<div class=""><b>Select earliest Date:</b> <input type="date" name="start" value="startd" ng-model= 'data.date' format="MMM DD YYYY" separator="/"></div>
```

Then I have it generated using this

```
{{ data.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }} or {{ data.date | date: 'MMMM dd, yyyy' }}
```

Is there a way to set a filter to choose ANY date between today's date and whichever date they choose in the dropdown?

How would I do something like this for example???

```
**{{ data.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' - 6 weeks }}**
```

Comment: you have to use ng-max for that

Comment: could I include that right in the filter?

Comment: I want to show any random date within the range two. I don't know how to do that.